# Get error logs from sshfs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sftp, sshfs

I connect a network drive using sshfs on my ubuntu computer. Over time the drive disconnects. How can I find out, why this happens? I.e., how can I get a log from sshfs.

I use Ubuntu and the following command: `sudo sshfs -o allow_other user@server:/mydir /mnt/mydir`

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the ssh daemon logs on the remote server?

Comment: `sshfs` uses SSH, so I expect settings in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `~/.ssh/config` apply. Do you use `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax`? Please read [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446441/108618), it may be what happens. (And maybe [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585887/108618) for broader context.)